# How to convert each word of each row to numeric value of a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp

This dataframe is given to me.

[image]

My desired output using a dictionary is like this

```
**Given the following dictionary:-** 
d = {'I': 30,'am': 45,'good': 90,'boy': 50,'We':100,'are':70,'going':110}
```

[image]

How to do this using python ..
I have tried like this but have failed :(

```
dataframe['new'] = data['documents'].apply(lambda x: dictionary[x])
```

Kindly help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide you input dataframes as DataFrame constructors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode` to get words then map with your dict and reshape your dataframe:

```
MAPPING = {'I': 30,'am': 45,'good': 90,'boy': 50,'We':100,'are':70,'going':110}

df['documents'] = (df['documents'].str.split().explode().map(MAPPING).astype(str)
                                  .groupby(level=0).agg(list).str.join(' '))
print(df)

# Output
   id    documents
0   0  30 45 90 50
1   1   100 70 110
2   2    30 45 110
```

**Step by step**

Phase 1: Explode

```
# Split phrase into words
>>> out = df['documents'].str.split()
0    [I, am, good, boy]
1      [We, are, going]
2        [I, am, going]
Name: documents, dtype: object

# Explode lists into scalar values
>>> out = out.explode()
0        I
0       am
0     good
0      boy
1       We
1      are
1    going
2        I
2       am
2    going
Name: documents, dtype: object
```

Phase 2: Transform

```
# Convert words with your dict mapping and convert as string
>>> out = out.map(MAPPING).astype(str)
0     30
0     45
0     90
0     50
1    100
1     70
1    110
2     30
2     45
2    110
Name: documents, dtype: object  # <- .astype(str)
```

Phase 3: Reshape

```
# Group by index (level=0) then aggregate to a list
>>> out = out.groupby(level=0).agg(list)
0    [30, 45, 90, 50]
1      [100, 70, 110]
2       [30, 45, 110]
Name: documents, dtype: object

# Join your list of words
>>> out = out.str.join(' ')
0    30 45 90 50
1     100 70 110
2      30 45 110
Name: documents, dtype: object
```

Comment: Amazing! It worked. But It will immensely help me if you explain the code a bit because this one liner consists so much of thing which seems magical to me

Answer (score 1):

Instead of searching for `d[x]` where `x` is the whole sentence, you should search for `d[w]` for every word `w` in the sentence `x`.

You can split a string into a list of words using `.split()`. Then you can use a list comprehension, or `map`, to search the dictionary for every word in the list:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(3), 'documents': ['I am good boy', 'We are going', 'I am going']})

print(df)
#    id      documents
# 0   0  I am good boy
# 1   1   We are going
# 2   2     I am going

d = {'I': 30,'am': 45,'good': 90,'boy': 50,'We':100,'are':70,'going':110}

df['new'] = df['documents'].apply(lambda s: list(map(d.get, s.split())))

# or alternatively:
# df['new'] = df['documents'].apply(lambda s: [d.get(w) for w in s.split()])

print(df)
#    id      documents               new
# 0   0  I am good boy  [30, 45, 90, 50]
# 1   1   We are going    [100, 70, 110]
# 2   2     I am going     [30, 45, 110]
```

Important note: I suggest using `d.get(w)` rather than `d[w]`. If `w` is not in the dictionary, then attempting `d[w]` will raise an exception. However, `d.get` accepts a default value, and will never raise an exception. By default, `d.get(w)` will return `None` if `w` is not in `d`, but you can specify the default value yourself:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': range(4), 'documents': ['I am good boy', 'We are going', 'I am going', 'I am good words not going in dictionary']})

df['new'] = df['documents'].apply(lambda s: [d.get(w, 37) for w in s.split()])

print(df)
#    id                                documents                                new
# 0   0                            I am good boy                   [30, 45, 90, 50]
# 1   1                             We are going                     [100, 70, 110]
# 2   2                               I am going                      [30, 45, 110]
# 3   3  I am good words not going in dictionary  [30, 45, 90, 37, 37, 110, 37, 37]
```